# sendNotificationEmail doesn't work with service account (Drive API v3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I can't send an email notification when I add permission in a file with the drive `API v3`, before May, it works fine but since 14/05/2020 doesn't send an email with `node v10.16.3`.

I do this to authenticate:

[image]

and then when I add permission:

[image]

Response from drive service

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snXLU.png)

Comment: What are the error messages and stack trace?

Comment: There is no errors, everything is status 200, it just doesn't send the mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/142086394) has been reported on Google's Public Issue tracker

- Basically, Service acocunts seemed temporarily not be able to send notification emails on their own behalf.
- The notification emails are however sent and received as expected if you use [impersonation](https://medium.com/google-cloud/impersonating-users-with-google-cloud-platform-service-accounts-ba762db09092).
- This issue seemed to be fixed, but if it reappeared again, you should mention it in a comment of the issue.
- In the meantime, use impersonation as a workaround.
- Impersonation is in general a good practice when using service accounts.